# Alternative for enqueueHTTPRequestOperation in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, afhttpclient

We need to download files concurrently in our application.

In earlier version of AFNetworking we have downloaded 2 files concurrently by using the code below:

```
(AFHTTPClient)
[_httpClient.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:MAX_CONCURRENT_OPERATIONS];
[self.httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:downloadObj.downloadOperation];
```

Now we want to upgrade our AFNetworking to 2.0.

Instead of `AFHTTPClient` we are using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and able to set

```
  setMaxConcurrentOperationCount: value
```

But we are manually starting our download process. I am looking for alternative(enqueueHTTPRequestOperation in 2.0) for this to download automatically.

Comment: I'm also looking for alternatives. have you found a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the property `operationQueue` in `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`

So maybe try this

```
[self.operationQueue addOperation:downloadObj.downloadOperation];
```

Comment: i used this, download starting automatically but,even after setting the setMaxConcurrentOperationCount: all the downloads are starting at a time.